# Descargar imágenes mediante CURL PHP

Tags: php, sql, curl

Estoy intentando descargar imágenes a través del CURL y guardarlas en una carpeta. Lo que hago es recorrer una base de datos donde hay un campo que se llama imagen. Lo que pasa es que si me funciona, pero es como que no lo termina. No sé si sera porque es una petición muy grande, o no sé. 
El código en sí funciona bien, porque me descarga una parte de las imágenes, pero la otra parte no sé porqué no.

El código es el siguiente:

```
$cont = 0;
        while($contenido = repo($contenidos)){
            $cont++;
            $imgArray = imagenesTexto($contenido->texto);
            foreach($imgArray as $img){

                $ruta = "http://www.miweb.es/" . $img;
                echo $ruta . "<br>";
                $imgExplode = explode("/", $img);
                $imagenJPG = array_pop($imgExplode);
                $rutaCarpeta = implode("/", $imgExplode)."/";

                // CURL
                $metodocurl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($metodocurl, CURLOPT_URL, $ruta);
                curl_setopt($metodocurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($metodocurl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
                $curlDatos = curl_exec ($metodocurl);
                curl_close ($metodocurl);


                // Declaramos la ruta para almacenar los archivos descargados
                $rutaCarpeta = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $rutaCarpeta;
                // Verificamos si existe, sino se crea
                if (!file_exists($rutaCarpeta)) {
                    mkdir($rutaCarpeta, 0777, true);
                }

                // Ruta de la descarga
                $rutadescarga = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $img;
                $miarchivo = fopen($rutadescarga, "w+");

                // Insertamos en la carpeta la imagen
                fputs($miarchivo, $curlDatos);

            }

            fclose($miarchivo);
        }
        echo "Importación de imágenes completada: " . $cont;
```

Otro dato, es que hago un `echo` de cada ruta de la imagen en las primeras líneas. Me pinta sólo como 400 (de 3000 +-), y el `echo` del final ni lo pinta.

Me podéis decir qué es lo qué pasa? Muchas graciaaass!1

Comment: No se entiende del todo lo que quieres hacer, pero me parece una muy mala idea abrir `cURL` dentro del bucle. Por ejemplo, ¿si comentas toda la parte relativa al `cURL` el código termina? ¿Revisaste el log de errores para ver exactamente cuál es el problema?

Comment: Buenos días! Sí, cuando comento se me ejecuta el código entero. ¿Entonces abro `cURL` antes del `while`? Creo que también puede ser el tiempo de espera del `cURL`. Voy a intentar cambiarlo a ver que tal.

Comment: que tal si cambias el curl por el [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

Vale, lo que pasaba es que tardaba tanto en ejecutarse que se paraba debido al `tiempo lìmite del cURL`. He insertado estas líneas en mi código y me ha funcionado:

```
// Las dos siguientes lineas sirven para no parar la ejecución ya que 
                // la petición cURL es demasiado larga
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```